# HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile does not output

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I am not a software engineer but wrote quite some Google Apps scripts. However I've got virtually no experience on the GUI side, but now I implemented a script for seat reservations which requires an input dialog (working) and a confirmation page (the problem).

The entire script works, but the resulting confirmation page remains empty.

The relevant code snipplet (all used variables are properly defined):

```
// Make a web page
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('thank_you.html');
template.msg = 'Eine Buchung erscheint demnächst in Ihrem <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/">persönlichen Kalender</a>.';
template.email = email;
template.header = title;
Logger.log(template.getCodeWithComments());
return template.evaluate().setTitle('Vielen Dank für Ihre Buchung');
```

And the getCSS() function:

```
function getCSS(){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('css.html');
  return template.getRawContent();
}
```

I am am using the same approach to create the input form which is working,but this simple confirmation page remains emppty.
I tried many different approaches for hours but I do not see the problem! What am I missing?

The resulting execution log does not show any problem, as far as I can see it, at least I can see, that values are assigned:

> [17-11-23 11:36:33:447 PST]
>   HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile([thank_you.html]) [0.001 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:451 PST] Function.apply([[]]) [0.004 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:452 PST] Logger.log([(function() { return eval('var
>   output = HtmlService.initTemplate(); output._ =  \'\n\';\n' + 
>   //    'output._ =  \'\n\' +\n' +
>   , []]...) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:453 PST] Function.apply([[]])
>   [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:453 PST] HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
>   [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:454 PST] HtmlOutput.append([ ])
>   [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:455 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>       ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:457 PST] HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile([css.html]) [0.001 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:457 PST] Function.apply([[]]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23
>   11:36:33:458 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ## page{
>
> ```
>   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   margin-top:50px;
>   padding-top:260px;
>   text-align: left;
>   font-size: 1.3em;
>   background: no-repeat 0px 0px;  ]...) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:458 PST] HtmlOutput.append([   </head> ]) [0 seconds]
> ```
>
> [17-11-23 11:36:33:459 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ```
>     <h3>]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:459 PST] HtmlOutput.appendUntrusted([Buchung Scheibe 1]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23
> ```
>
> 11:36:33:460 PST] HtmlOutput.append([ ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23
>   11:36:33:460 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:460 PST] HtmlOutput.appendUntrusted([heinz.ruffieux@ondemandmanagement.net]) [0
>   seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:461 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:461 PST] HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ```
>    <p>]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:462 PST] HtmlOutput.append([Eine Buchung erscheint demnächst in Ihrem <a
> ```
>
> target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/">persönlichen
>   Kalender.]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:462 PST]
>   HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:463 PST]
>   HtmlOutput.append([
>
> ```
>  </div>
>  </body> </html> ]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:463 PST] HtmlOutput.append([]) [0 seconds] [17-11-23 11:36:33:464 PST]
> ```
>
> HtmlOutput.setTitle([Vielen Dank für Ihre Buchung]) [0 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:549 PST] HtmlOutput.getContent() [0 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:549 PST] HtmlOutput.getTitle() [0 seconds]
>   [17-11-23 11:36:33:551 PST] Execution succeeded [0.506 seconds total
>   runtime]

However, the Logger.log(template.getCodeWithComments()); then shows the following, empty output:

```
doPost()
(function() { return eval('var output = HtmlService.initTemplate(); output._ =  \'<html>\\n\';\n' +  // <html>
  'output._ =  \'<head>\\n\' +\n' +                                                                  // <head>
  '  \'    \'; output._ =  getCSS(); \n' +                                                           //     <?!= getCSS()?>
  'output._ =  \'   </head>\\n\';\n' +                                                               //    </head>
  'output._ =  \'   \\n\' +\n' +                                                                     //    
  '  \'   <body>\\n\' +\n' +                                                                         //    <body>
  '  \'     <div id=\\\"page\\\" >\\n\' +\n' +                                                       //      <div id="page" >
  '  \' \\n\' +\n' +                                                                                 //  
  '  \'        <h3>\'; output._$ =  header ; output._ =  \'</h3>\\n\';\n' +                          //         <h3><?= header ?></h3>
  'output._ =  \'        \\n\' +\n' +                                                                //         
  '  \'        <p>\\n\' +\n' +                                                                       //         <p>
  '  \'        \'; output._$ =  email; \n' +                                                         //         <?= email?>
  'output._ =  \'        </p>\\n\';\n' +                                                             //         </p>
  'output._ =  \'           \\n\' +\n' +                                                             //            
  '  \'       <p>\'; output._ =  msg ; output._ =  \'</p>\\n\';\n' +                                 //        <p><?!= msg ?></p>
  'output._ =  \'       \\n\' +\n' +                                                                 //        
  '  \'     \\n\' +\n' +                                                                             //      
  '  \'\\n\' +\n' +                                                                                  // 
  '  \'       \\n\' +\n' +                                                                           //        
  '  \'     </div>\\n\' +\n' +                                                                       //      </div>
  '  \' \\n\' +\n' +                                                                                 //  
  '  \' \\n\' +\n' +                                                                                 //  
  '  \' </body>\\n\' +\n' +                                                                          //  </body>
  '  \'</html>\\n\';\n' +                                                                            // </html>
  '\n' +                                                                                             // 
  '/* End of user code */\n' +
  'output.$out.append(\'\');');
})();
```

The thank_you.html file:

> ```
> <html> <head>
> <?!= getCSS()?>    </head>
>    <body>
>  <div id="page" >
>
>     <h3><?= header ?></h3>
>
>     <p>
>     <?= email?>
>     </p>
>
>    <p><?!= msg ?></p>
>
>  </div>
> ```

The css file (used in the working form as well):

```
    <style>


#page{
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin-top:50px;
      padding-top:260px;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      background: no-repeat 0px 0px;
      width:600px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      border:1px solid #DDD;
      padding-bottom:20px;
      padding-left:20px;
    }

    input#email{
    font-size:1.1em;
    }

    input#submit{
      -webkit-appearance: button;
       margin-top:10px;
       height: 50px;
       font-size:1.7em;

    }

  .submitbutton {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      font-size:30px;
     }

   .small{
      font-size:12px;
  }
</style>
```

Is there anyone who sees the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Heinz

Comment: I don't see a function named `getCSS()`?  Also, for this line  `<?= header ?>`  Is `header` referring to a global variable in a .gs file?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Sandy. My appologies, I forgot to post the getCSS() function and included it now in my question above. 
The <?= header ?> should refer to template.header = title; in my snipplet above, I assume

Comment: In the browser, open the Development Tools.  In Chrome, hit the f12 key. Are there any messages in the console?  Also, remove the scriptlets that are NOT for the CSS, and put put plain text in the HTML.  Instead of using `template.msg` just use `msg = "my message";` and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, found something in the browsers dev tools, which might be the problem, but I am not sure what causes it. As I stated above, I use the exact same approach at another place in the script to generate a simple webpage and there it works. The other simple webpage also set's "sameorigin".
Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/mydomain.com/macros/s/AKfycbz0xtDne0U1IPLFFEUIJrn7M6XZ7trdnE-73IdZ89iZn_Qw_QVl/exec' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
Any idea?

Comment: Finally found the problem! Under HTML5 you need to explicitely allow sameorigin by stating: 
return template
          .evaluate()
         .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

This thread resolved my problem: stackoverflow.com/a/40843413/1955916
Thanks Sandy for pointing me into the right direction!